# How to make salesforce app available in multiple language?

Tags: translation-workbench

I want to make my sales force app available in multiple language like Spanish, dutch etc up to 15 languages. so that depend on the local language of the user they can access the app.

Is it possible in any way..

any help will be appreciated.. Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

You need to be more specific on what you need to localise. The usual approach is to leverage [Translation Workbench](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_wbench.htm&language=nl) for your object fields,  Details on language supported and what kind of metadata you can localise, see [this](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_translations.htm) link.

To enable Translation Setting for Custom objects, associated fields, picklist values etc.

1. Setup -> Translation Setting -> Enable
2. Add required language support required for Profile level
3. Select Required languages from drop down & user for which languages need to be supported
4. Save language
5. Do the same for any components & field level translations